# PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR: relation "boards" already exists

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a model in no2 branch, then I find some error and decided to delete this branch and start a new one.

But when I rewrote this model and db:migrate , it told me that this table already exist.

I tried db:rollback but didn't work, and the migrate:status showed that:
[image]

and my schema.rb is empty

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my db & re db:migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql script, to remove a record from schema_migrations table where version is 20191215065743.
Further, if the boards table exist, drop it using psql command.